# Fill blank cells in pivot table as a reference to a value above

Tags: excel, blank-line

Messing with a pivot table and its behaviour. I have many categories describing each row, but for my own needs, I want to have every row's cell filled regarding its category. Not to have blank cells, as default, refering category name's cell.

For example given below, desired solution is to fill A6-A24 with value from A5 and then category changes to e.g. ,,Region Detail" and the blank row's filling changes too to ,,Region Detail" (you can simply imagine it in DATE_KEY column). Any methods?

[image]

Comment: Found a walk-around:
1. Copy-paste data from a pivot table (select whole table -> paste special -> select ,,values" radiobutton)
2. Select all blank cells (ctrl+g -> -> ,,special" -> select ,,blanks" radiobutton)
3. Type in formula textbox equal sign and then type up arrow (so you just click two buttons on a keyboard) to construct formula ,,=[cell above]" 
4. Click ctrl+enter
This should fulfill all the blanks with nearest value specified above them.
Note: Same procedure for filling blanks below/on left/on right - just type appropriate arrow in point no 3.

Answer (score 2):

Put your cursor on any cell of the Pivot Table. Now you will see some new options in the Menu Bar.

Click on **Design**. Go to **Report Layout** and click on **Repeat All Item Labels**